# html5 - How to save binary data to html5 file system

Tags: html, filesystems, binary-data

i want to save a dropped image into the html5 filesystem. The problem is that i do not know how to write binary data into the file system with the file api. Below are parts of my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();  

reader.onloadend = function(e)
{
      var data = e.target.result;

      // Open File System code (Codes Omitted)
      // Create file           (Codes Omitted)

      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter)
      {
           // This is the problem, the file is create, something is written to the file
           // because the size is exact same with the dragged file (image). But when i     
           // try to view the file (image), it displays nothing.

           var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder
           bb.append(data);
           fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob(""));
      }

}

reader.readAsBinaryString(cur_file);
```

I intentionally left out some codes like the file system and file creation. I only need help with saving binary data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter a similar issue
Since you didn't parse your code here,I assume that you read the image in a wrong way,
maybe
You read the `cur_file` as binary string,Did your `fileReader` read it by `readAsText` method
Since the file stores binaryString,If your `fileReader` read it by another way,e.g `readAsDataURL`,that means you encode it again,so you couldn't get the right answer